# Why is there a performance difference between LINQ (c#) vs Seq (f#)

Tags: c#, performance, linq, f#

I made very simple C# and F# test programs.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Remainder(int num)
        {
            return num % 2;
        }
        static int SumOfremainders(IEnumerable<int> list)
        {
            var sum = 0;
            foreach (var num in list)
            {
                sum += Remainder(num);
            }
            return sum;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            var nums = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000000);
            sw.Start();
            var a = SumOfremainders(nums);
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Duration " + (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds));
            Console.WriteLine("Sum of remainders: {0}", a);
        }
    }
}


let remainder x = x % 2   

let sumORemainders n = 
   n
   |> Seq.map(fun n-> remainder n)
   |> Seq.sum

let seqb = Seq.init 10000000(fun n->n)
let timer =System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
timer.Start()
let a =(sumORemainders seqb )
timer.Stop()
printfn "Elapsed Time: "
System.Console.WriteLine timer.ElapsedMilliseconds
printfn "Sum of squares of 1-100: %d"  a


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    0 // return an integer exit code
```

c# 71 ms
f# 1797 ms

I made second version from F# which work similar than c#

```
let remainder x = x % 2   

let sumORemainders (input:seq<int>)  =
    let mutable sum = 0
    let en = input.GetEnumerator()
    while (en.MoveNext()) do 
        sum <- sum + remainder en.Current 
    sum


let seqb = Seq.init 10000000(fun n->n)
let timer =System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
timer.Start()
let a =(sumORemainders seqb )
timer.Stop()
printfn "Elapsed Time: "
System.Console.WriteLine timer.ElapsedMilliseconds
printfn "Sum of squares of 1-100: %d"  a


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    0 // return an integer exit code
```

but the result not not changed significantly (1650ms)

I don't understand the big difference in speed between the two languages.

The two programs have very similar IL code, both use IEnumerable, moreover the F# replace the function call with operation.

I rewrote c# code based on f# IL code.

```
static int SumOfremainders(IEnumerable<int> list)
        {
            var sum = 0;
            IEnumerator<int> e = list.GetEnumerator();
            while (e.MoveNext())
            {
                sum += e.Current % 2;
            }
            return sum;
        }
```

The IL code of two programs are same but the speed still very different.
I found the IL difference thanks for  Foggy Finder

The slow code

```
[CompilationMapping(SourceConstructFlags.Module)]
public static class Program
{
    [Serializable]
    internal class seqb@18 : FSharpFunc<int, int>
    {
        internal seqb@18()
        {
        }

        public override int Invoke(int n)
        {
            return n;
        }
    }

    [CompilationMapping(SourceConstructFlags.Value)]
    public static IEnumerable<int> seqb
    {
        get
        {
            return $Program.seqb@18;
        }
    }
```

The fast code

```
[CompilationMapping(SourceConstructFlags.Module)]
public static class Program
{
    [CompilationMapping(SourceConstructFlags.Value)]
        public static int[] seqb
        {
            get
            {
                return $Program.seqb@20;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't agree that the question is a duplicate. The other question is open whereas this is much more specific. However I think the OP should rephrase the question to include `Seq/LINQ` as this is more likely the issue (`LINQ` is slow `Seq` is slower)

Comment: This is because your C# code and F# are actually different.

Comment: this : `let seqb = Seq.init 10000000(fun n->n)` not equal to `var nums = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000000);`

Comment: you can try this: `let seqb = seq {0..10000000}` instead

Comment: although it will still be a big difference. But in F# you can write: `let a = seqb |> Seq.sumBy remainder`

Comment: It's irritating that this is marked as a duplicate (which I disagree with) because this prevents a proper explaination of what is going on. Tip: `Seq.init` here is the culprit: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L274 . In case anyone care more details here: https://gist.github.com/mrange/09ba6d7541468de49426eeb81a8b660c

Comment: if you want improve performance you can just init start seq as array: `let seqb = [|0..10000000|]`

Comment: I posted the code I created here: https://gist.github.com/mrange/58254f4339bc194bbc96c4ff83ba16c9

Comment: btw, I just say...you can use `for` in `F#` `let sumORemainders input  =
    let mutable sum = 0
    for num in input do
        sum <- sum + remainder num
    sum`

Comment: yes, : let seqb = Seq.init 10000000(fun n->n) not equal to var nums = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000000) but I don't measure the initialization

Comment: @FuleSnabel - I've reopened it

Comment: let a =seqb |> Seq.sumBy(remainder) 3550 ms let a = sumORemainders(seqb) and let sumORemainders n = 
   n
   |> Seq.sumBy(remainder) 254 ms

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The primary reason OP sees a performance difference is because `Seq.init` in F# is slow. The reason for it is that in each iteration `Seq.upto` (which `Seq.init` uses) allocates a new `Lazy<_>` object. You can see this in `Seq` [source](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L274).
If you have a low overhead function like `fun n -> n % 2` the cost of a new `Lazy<_>` object as well as evaluating it (mutex lock and unlock) takes a significant amount of time.

The second reason OP sees a performance difference is that `Seq` in F# is slow in general. This is being remedied by manofstick in this [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/pull/1570)

With the PR inplace F# `Seq` will perform very well compared to the alternatives that exists (some details [here](http://gist.github.com/mrange/09ba6d7541468de49426eeb81a8b660c))

With all this said I prepared some comparisons of different ways to do the computation posted by the user (apart from the obvious `total / 2`).

```
open CsPerfs
open Nessos.Streams
open System.Diagnostics
open System.Linq
open System.Numerics


// now () returns current time in milliseconds since start
let now : unit -> int64 =
  let sw = Stopwatch ()
  sw.Start ()
  fun () -> sw.ElapsedMilliseconds

// time estimates the time 'action' repeated a number of times
let time repeat action =
  let inline cc i       = System.GC.CollectionCount i

  let v                 = action ()

  System.GC.Collect (2, System.GCCollectionMode.Forced, true)

  let bcc0, bcc1, bcc2  = cc 0, cc 1, cc 2
  let b                 = now ()

  for i in 1..repeat do
    action () |> ignore

  let e = now ()
  let ecc0, ecc1, ecc2  = cc 0, cc 1, cc 2

  v, (e - b), ecc0 - bcc0, ecc1 - bcc1, ecc2 - bcc2

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
  let count = 10000000

  let outers = 
    [|
      1000
    |]

  for outer in outers do
    let inner = count / outer

    let fsImperativeTest () = 
      let mutable sum = 0
      for n = 0 to inner-1 do
        sum <- sum + n % 2
      sum

    let fsLinqTest () = 
      Enumerable.Range(0, inner).Select(fun n -> n % 2).Sum()
    let fsNessosTest () = 
      Stream.initInfinite id
      |> Stream.take inner
      |> Stream.map (fun n -> n % 2)
      |> Stream.sum
    let fsOpTest () = 
      let remainder x = x % 2   
      let sumORemainders (input:seq<int>)  =
          let mutable sum = 0
          use en = input.GetEnumerator()
          while (en.MoveNext()) do 
              sum <- sum + remainder en.Current 
          sum
      let seqb = Seq.init inner id
      sumORemainders seqb
    let fsSseTest () = 
      let inc         = Vector<int>.One
      let one         = Vector<int>.One
      let mutable sum = Vector<int>.Zero
      let mutable n   = Vector<int> [|0..3|]
      for n4 = 0 to inner/4-1 do
        n <- n + inc
        sum <- sum + (n &&& one)
      sum.[0] + sum.[1] + sum.[2] + sum.[3]
    let fsSeqTest () = 
      Seq.init inner id 
        |> Seq.map (fun n -> n % 2)
        |> Seq.sum
    let fsSeqVariantTest () = 
      seq { for n = 0 to inner-1 do yield n }
        |> Seq.map (fun n -> n % 2)
        |> Seq.sum

    let csImperativeTest = 
      let f = Perfs.CsImperativeTest inner
      fun () -> f.Invoke ()
    let csLinqTest = 
      let f = Perfs.CsLinqTest inner
      fun () -> f.Invoke ()
    let csOpTest =
      let f = Perfs.CsOpTest inner
      fun () -> f.Invoke ()

    let tests =
      [|
        "fsImperativeTest"  , fsImperativeTest
        "fsLinqTest"        , fsLinqTest
        "fsNessosTest"      , fsNessosTest
        "fsOpTest"          , fsOpTest
        "fsSeqTest"         , fsSeqTest
        "fsSeqVariantTest"  , fsSeqVariantTest
        "fsSseTest"         , fsSseTest
        "csImperativeTest"  , csImperativeTest
        "csLinqTest"        , csLinqTest
        "csOpTest"          , csOpTest
      |]

    printfn "Test run - total count: %d, outer: %d, inner: %d" count outer inner

    for name, test in tests do
      printfn "Running %s..." name
      let v, ms, cc0, cc1, cc2 = time outer test
      printfn "  it took %d ms - collection count is %d,%d,%d - result is %A" ms cc0 cc1 cc2 v 


  0
```

The matching C# code:

```
namespace CsPerfs
{
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;

    public static class Perfs
    {
      static int Remainder(int num)
      {
          return num % 2;
      }

      static int SumOfremainders(IEnumerable<int> list)
      {
          var sum = 0;
          foreach (var num in list)
          {
              sum += Remainder(num);
          }
          return sum;
      }

      public static Func<int> CsOpTest (int count)
      {
        return () => SumOfremainders (Enumerable.Range(1, count));
      }

      public static Func<int> CsImperativeTest (int count)
      {
        return () =>
          {
            var sum = 0;
            for (var n = 0; n < count; ++n)
            {
              sum += n % 2;
            }
            return sum;
          };
      }

      public static Func<int> CsLinqTest (int count)
      {
        return () => Enumerable.Range (0, count).Select (n => n % 2).Sum ();
      }
    }
}
```

The performance numbers seen on my machine (Intel Core I5) running on .NET 4.6.1 64bit:

```
Test run - total count: 10000000, outer: 1000, inner: 10000
Running fsImperativeTest...
  it took 20 ms - collection count is 0,0,0 - result is 5000
Running fsLinqTest...
  it took 124 ms - collection count is 0,0,0 - result is 5000
Running fsNessosTest...
  it took 56 ms - collection count is 0,0,0 - result is 5000
Running fsOpTest...
  it took 1320 ms - collection count is 661,0,0 - result is 5000
Running fsSeqTest...
  it took 1477 ms - collection count is 661,0,0 - result is 5000
Running fsSeqVariantTest...
  it took 512 ms - collection count is 0,0,0 - result is 5000
Running fsSseTest...
  it took 2 ms - collection count is 0,0,0 - result is 5000
Running csImperativeTest...
  it took 19 ms - collection count is 0,0,0 - result is 5000
Running csLinqTest...
  it took 122 ms - collection count is 0,0,0 - result is 5000
Running csOpTest...
  it took 58 ms - collection count is 0,0,0 - result is 5000
Press any key to continue . . .
```

`Seq` does the worst and also consumes memory. If both F# and C# code uses LINQ there's no real difference as expected. Nessos is a high-performance data pipeline for F# (and C#) that does significantly better.

"Hard-coding" a for loop does better still and the fastest solution is to use SSE through `System.Numerics.Vectors`. Unfortunately `System.Numerics.Vectors` doesn't support `%` which makes the comparison a bit unfair.

So the difference is not so much a language issue but a library issue.